# SQL: Differenciate between mutliple conditions on a failed update

Tags: mysql, sql

My problem: I have an update that has multiple conditions:

`UPDATE GAMES
 SET player2 = player2ID
 WHERE GAMES.id = gameId
 AND GAMES.player2 IS NULL;`

Normally, when I run updates with a single condition, I can check if the amount of rows affected was 0 and know exactly why the insert didnt work and can give the user the appropiate error message with ease.

However with multiple conditions, just knowing that no rows were affected is not enough. Either the game was full already or the game didnt exist.

How would I find out which condition wasnt met?

Comment: hard to imagine this SQL code. Maybe You think `insert ... select` (diferente syntax at different db)

Comment: Your query makes no sense, either syntactically or logically.  Perhaps you want an `update`?

Comment: Ah yeah of course lol. Update it is

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO GAMES
VALUES(player2ID)
WHERE GAMES.id = gameId
AND GAMES.player2 IS NULL;
```

Comment: Please make this a full answer, not just a code answer with no explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SELECT before INSERT to check what you need

```
SELECT id, player2 FROM GAMES where id=gameId Or
```

If I understand you right you need this

```
SELECT player2 FROM GAMES where id=gameId
```

And if this statement is not empty then there is a player2.

Comment: I am looking for a solution where I must not request the data to my server, check and then write back to db. That solution would be open to race conditions.

Comment: If there is a player2 what you are expecting to do db?

Comment: I am expecting the update to then throw an error. I want to then see according to the error if the player2 existed or if the game didnt exist